# Implementing jQuery isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to implementing the awesome isotope plugin http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

I am facing a problem with a filter and am not able to find a workaround for it so far:

What is happening is that when "ALL" filter link is clicked, all items are displayed but when any other filter link is clicked, all the items disappear. I would really appreciate some help:)

I have set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPfay/)

And here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul id="portfolio-filter">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".website">WEBSITE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".logos">LOGOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".illustrations">ILLUSTRATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".brand">BRAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ui">UI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".icons">ICONS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="portfolio-container">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-2">
            <li><div class="website"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-01.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="logos"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-02.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="illustrations"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-03.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="brand"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-04.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="ui"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-05.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="icons"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-06.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="website"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-07.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="logos"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-08.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="illustrations"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-09.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="brand"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-10.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="ui"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-11.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="icons"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-12.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="website"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-13.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="logos"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-14.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="illustrations"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-15.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
            <li><div class="brand"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-16.jpg" alt=""></a></div></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /portfolio-container -->
</div><!-- /large-12 columns -->
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // cache container
  var $container = $('#portfolio-container');
  // initialize isotope
  $container.isotope({
    // options...
  });

  // filter items when filter link is clicked
  $('#portfolio-filter li a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: does adding commas work? `data-filter="*,.ui"`

Comment: I think it's to do with the HTML structure. The isotope demo applies classes to the child elements of the container. You apply classes to grandchild elements. Try getting rid of the `<div>` elements and have the `<img>s` directly inside the `<li>s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apply the selector classes directly to the `<li>` elements inside `<ul class="small-block-grid-2">` and purge the divs from around the images.
2. Make sure all the img tags are properly closed, `<img ..... />`.
3. Apply isotope to `<ul class="small-block-grid-2">`

### HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-container">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2">
        <li class="website"><a href="#"><img src="img/portfolio/small-01.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

### javascript

```
var $container = $('.small-block-grid-2');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
    // options...
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#portfolio-filter li a').on('click', function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPfay/3/show/)